# What are the differences between the older row_number() and the newer OFFSET + FETCH based pagination in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have few questions in context of the older row_number (SQL Server 2008) and the newer OFFSET + FETCH (SQL Server 2012) paging mechanism provided by SQL Server 2012.

1. What are the limitations with row_number()?
2. Is OFFSET + FETCH an improved replacement for row_number()?
3. Are there any use-cases which could only be sufficed using one and not the other?
4. Are there any performance differences between the two? If yes, which one is recommended?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked around? See this rather comprehensive answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30210/why-are-there-execution-plan-differences-between-offset-fetch-and-the-old-st

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` works fine - it's just more work than necessary; you need to write a "skeleton" CTE around your actual query, add the `ROW_NUMBER()` column to your output set, and then filter on that.

Using the new `OFFSET / FETCH` is simpler - and yes, it's also better for performance, as these two links can show you:

- [New T-SQL features in SQL Server 2012](http://www.dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch)
- [Comparing performance for different SQL Server paging](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2696/comparing-performance-for-different-sql-server-paging-methods/)

So overall: if you're *using* SQL Server 2012 - then you should *definitely* use `OFFSET/FETCH` rather than `ROW_NUMBER()` for paging

Comment: This look quite honest, but I wonder how can I force EF use ofsets with 2012 sql server?

Comment: I have several reasons to not agree with your conclusion, it is not as straightforward as you put it:
The first link you mention does not do any performance comparison: _I’m not intending to draw any conclusions on this because I am not doing any thorough testing here._
The 2nd link does not mention what is the number of rows the test was performed on, and the OFFSET/FETCH approach is susceptible of being poor with large tables (see here http://www.mssqlgirl.com/paging-function-performance-in-sql-server-2012.html)

Comment: @lcfd: That mssqlgirl article doesn't compare OFFSET/FETCH with ROW_NUMBER: it only compares it with techniques that involve ordering by a known, unique, indexed, consecutive ID field. That's not applicable to many real-world situations.

Answer (score 2):

By definition `ROW_NUMBER` is a temporary value calculated when the query is run. `OFFSET / FETCH` is an option that you can specify for the `ORDER BY` clause.

In terms of speed, they both achieve great performance and the difference between each method depends on the columns that you specify in the `SELECT` clause and the Indexes that you have on your tables.

In the following 2 examples, you can see a difference between the two methods:

**1. Case when OFFSET / FETCH is faster:**

```
SELECT
    Id
FROM Orders
ORDER BY
    Id

OFFSET 50000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS ONLY

SELECT
    A.Id
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber FROM Orders
) AS A
WHERE
    A.RowNumber BETWEEN 50001 AND 55000
```

**2. Case when ROW_NUMBER() is faster:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Orders
ORDER BY
    Id
OFFSET 50000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS ONLY

SELECT
    A.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber FROM Orders
) AS A
WHERE
    A.RowNumber BETWEEN 50001 AND 55000
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this article which presents 3 techniques of paging compares their results in a chart. Might be helpful in deciding which approach you want to follow.

[Paging Function Performance in SQL Server 2012](https://www.mssqlgirl.com/paging-function-performance-in-sql-server-2012/)

All of the paging methods discussed work fine for smaller amounts of records, but not so much for larger quantities of data.